# Jersey endpoint returning 404 on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jersey

I've never used Jersey before and am having a noob problem in running a simple web app.

Here is my web.xml:

```
<display-name>microservice-ask</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.companyname.email.controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

And in my Controller that is in the path:

```
src\main\java\br\com\companyname\email\controller\EmailController.java
```

And inside this controller I have a simple endpoint:

```
@Path("/email")
public class EmailController {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        return "Got it!";
    }

}
```

When I run this on Tomcat inside Eclipse the endpoint

> http://localhost:8080/microservice-ask/rest/email/v1/sendEmail2

returns 404.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any endpoint with `email/v1/sendEmail2`, so error is expected

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with this endpoint, http://localhost:8080/projectx/rest/email/

```
@Path("/email")
public class EmailController {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
 public String getIt() {
    return "Got it!";
}
```

Produces "Got it!"

Comment: maybe its some configuration in eclipse? I tried to run it on Tomcat inside and outside eclipse, and still can't reach the endpoint for some reason.

Comment: If you need to match /v1/sendEmail2  etc, you need to use @Path("{subResources: regex}")